# how BANGDB handle the combination of time-series and graph together

Tags: graph, time-series, multi-model-database

with which query language we can manage the combination of graph data and time-series data and in which structure are they stored together

so you can create a schema that has the same structure as a graph in stream processing but can't see how to do the connection between the two data type